# What's the most basic way to create and handle multiple objects?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm trying to figure out what the most basic approach would be to effectively (or at least more effectively than what I have) create and manage objects. I know I could store them in a table when I create them which is what I currently do, but I'm not sure of a way to do it that would not be clunky to work with.

I don't have that much code to share, but here's a simple item class I made I'm trying to make use of composition although I still ended up using inheritance for the BaseItem.

```
function TestItem.new(x,y,w,h)
    local self = setmetatable(BaseItem.new(),TestItem)

    self.render = Render.new(x,y,w,h,Enum.GraphicType.Rectangle,{1,1,1})

    self.playerIsNear = false

    grid:insert({x = x, y = y, width = w, height = h}, self)    

    return self
end
```

And here's the main code that creates the objects.

```
function love.load()
    local screenWidth, screenHeight = love.graphics.getDimensions()

    grid = SpatialGrid.new(screenWidth, screenHeight, 70)

    player = Player.new(10,10,40,40)

    allObjects[1] = TestItem.new(300,50,20,20)
    allObjects[2] = TestItem.new(800,250,20,20)
    allObjects[3] = TestItem.new(600,300,20,20)
    allObjects[4] = TestItem.new(900,600,20,20)
end

function love.update(dt)
    player:update(dt)
    for _,object in ipairs(allObjects) do 
        object:update(dt)
    end
end

function love.draw()
    player:draw()
    for _,object in ipairs(allObjects) do 
        object:draw(player.input) -- the item objects need the players input component so they can display the interaction key
    end
end
```

Comment: What is "clunky" in your example?

Comment: Well in my code it's not that bad, but I'd imagine doing multiple lines of allObjects[num] = Entity.new() probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: You can keep all your coordinates in another array: `{{300,50,20,20}, {800,250,20,20},...}`